# Does the Monk passive skill "Resolve" stack with multiple Monks applying it?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

If you have 2 monks in your party, and they both have the passive "Resolve" ability which decreases enemy damage by 25% for 2.5 seconds when you inflict any damage, if they both hit the same enemy **will the Resolve effect stack and cause additional damage reduction?**

If it does stack, **is the effect truly additive, causing a 50% reduction?**

Enemy Damage * (.25 + .25) = Damage to Player

**Or is it multiplicative, causing less than a 50% reduction?**

Enemy Damage * .75 * .75 = Damage to Player

I wish the game were more clear on what abilities can stack, or we could somehow enable debuff status on a mob to see how things are being applied. For example, 2 monks with 2 of the same Mantra active will not stack, but with different mantras it will, and we know that because it appears in our status bar. But 2 monks using exploding palm on a mob can stack the effects, yet there is no way to know that without a little testing. A status bar for mobs would be an immense help.

Comment: If it does stack, it is probably multiplicatively, for balance reasons and consistency with other abilities. Here is some limited testing: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5151266881

Comment: Think of it this way: would blizzard allow a 4-monk group to reduce all damage by 100%?

Comment: @dpatch - I figured that would be the case, so at minimum I suspect it is multiplicative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, identical buffs/debuffs do not stack

Applying a buff or debuff that already exists simply refreshes the debuff already there

It should be noted that this is different for DoT debuffs. Per [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/68502/8462)

> The exception would be DOTS from multiple players. No player can
>   reset/remove your DOT. Everyone has their own DOT counters, so you can
>   apply the same DOT to one enemy as long as it is coming from two
>   different sources.

Comment: Well, it's not really a buff. Like I know the Mantras do not stack (same mantra), but certain debuffs, like Exploding Palm, can be applied by two seperate monks.

Comment: @Tater596 Exploding Palm applies a DoT, which is different than a debuff. I've updated my answer with a quote about DoTs

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5152406890)

"Dont think so, as far as i know only 1 buff/debuff of the same type can apply= it wont stack but it'll renew the duration"

If the speculation is correct the buff will just reset, which would make the effect last longer without any cumulative effect.

Comment: What about the cases of Exploding Palm for monks or Rend for Barbs? Are those abilities exception since they actually directly deal damage as opposed to reducing enemy damage?

Comment: This may not be correct. Abilities of the same type can apply according to the post I linked above and others on bnet. Testing there reveals they stack multiplicatively. I don't think the question of whether the same ability from multiple people stacks has been answered though.